# The hyperbolic space is a conformally compact Einstein manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

> How can we prove that the hyperbolic half space
> $\displaystyle\left(M=\mathbb{H}^{n+1} \ , \ g=\frac{|dy|^2+dx^2}{x^2}\right)$ where $x>0$ and
> $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a conformally compact Einstein manifold ?

I know that in order to define a conformally compact manifold , one needs to define a defining function $x$ of $\partial M$ (which is $\mathbb{R}^n$ in our case) in $M$ such that \begin{cases}x>0 \ 
\ \text{in} \ M \\x=0 \ \ \text{on} \ \partial M \\dx\neq0 \ \ \text{on} \ \partial M \end{cases} But in our case $\partial M=\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact .

Then how it is possible to define $(M,g)$ as a conformally compact manifold ? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Why is the boundary $\mathbb R^n$? From the definition, the hyperbolic half space has no boundary. What is the definition of conformally compact Einstein manifold?

Comment: @ArcticChar The boundary of a conformally compact manifold is a boundary "at infinity", not an intrinsic topological boundary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that the hyperbolic space is Einstein is a standard fact, so I'll focus on the conformal compactification.

Let me emphasize the fact that conformal compactifications are built to bring "infinity" back at finite distance (thanks to the conformal factor).
This procedure should then take care of **all** the different directions that are pointing toward infinity.
The problem with considering the topological boundary of the half space model of the hyperbolic space is that does not capture the conformal compactification: you are missing the point at infinity with $x \to \infty$.
If you add it, you obtain as a boundary the one point compactification of $\Bbb R^n$, which is just a sphere.
The ball model is more suitable to work with.

Let's then look at the ball model $(B(0;1),g)$, with $g = \frac{4}{(1-|x|^2)^2}g_{eucl}$, where $g_{eucl}$ is the Euclidean metric.
Consider $\rho(x) = \frac{1-|x|^2}{2}$ which is a defining function of the sphere $S(0;1) = \partial B(0;1)$.
Then $\rho^2 g = g_{eucl}$, and it follows that the hyperbolic space is conformally compact, with conformal compactification the closed ball $\bar{B}(0;1)$ and with conformal boundary $(S(0;1), [g_{eucl}|_S])$, the conformal class of the round sphere.

Comment: Ok, so far so good. Just one question, in the reference where I got the statement, they are referring $\partial M$ as the "conformal infinity" of $M$. So is this the reason why we are considering the point at infinity?

Comment: @am_11235... I don't know your reference. What I can tell is the standard definition: $M$ is conformally compact if there exists a compact manifold $\bar{M}$ **with boundary** $\partial M$ and a defining function $\rho$ for the boundary such that $\rho^2g$ extends as a metric on $\bar{M}$. The conformal boundary is then $(\partial M, [\rho^2g|{\partial M}])$. What you proposed doesn't fit in this definition right? Although we call it $\partial M$, it really is $\partial \bar{M}$.
One can show that this leads to uniqueness of the conformal boundary, independently of the choice of $\rho$.

Comment: That's the same definition I am using. I was just confused since we need $\bar{M}=\bar{\mathbb{R}_+^{n+1}}$ is compact, but $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact. But now it seems we need the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @am_11235... Note that one could argue that the hyperbolic space is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, so that there is no boundary at all. But this does not fit in the definition, and the boundary does not have to appear in any model.

Comment: I meant in *all* models