# volume of conformally compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

> Is it true that every conformally compact manifold has
> infinite volume?

I know that all conformally compact manifolds are not necessarily compact, e.g. the [Hyperbolic space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689940/the-hyperbolic-space-is-a-conformally-compact-einstein-manifold). So in this example the infinite volume thing works out. But how to prove that it is true for all such conformally compact manifolds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A conformally compact manifold is **never** compact (it is by definition the interior of a compact manifold with boundary).
Moreover, more is true: the volume of a conformally compact manifold is always infinite.
$\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}}$

Let $(M,g)$ be conformally compact of dimension $n\geqslant 2$.
Let $\rho \colon \overline{M}\to [0,+\infty)$ be a defining function for the boundary at infinity $\partial_{\infty}M$ (where $\overline{M} = M \cup \partial_{\infty}M$).
By the assumption, $\dx\rho \neq 0$ along the boundary, which implies that there exists a diffeomorphism
$M \setminus K_{\varepsilon} \to (0,\varepsilon)\times \partial_{\infty}M$, with $\varepsilon >0$ and $K_{\varepsilon} = \rho^{-1}([\varepsilon,+\infty))$ compact, such that the metric reads through this diffeomorphism
$$
g = \frac{\dx\rho\otimes \dx\rho + g_{\rho}}{\rho^2},
$$
where $(g_{\rho})_{\rho \in (0,\varepsilon)}$ is a smooth family of metrics on $\partial_{\infty}M$.
Moreover, as $\rho\to 0$, $g_{\rho}$ converges to a Riemannian metric $g_0$.
Let $(\dx\mathrm{vol}_{\rho})_{\rho\in [0,\varepsilon)}$ be the Riemannian volume forms of $(g_{\rho})_{\rho\in[0,\varepsilon)}$.
There exists a smooth function $\lambda \colon [0,\varepsilon) \times \partial_{\infty}M \to (0,+\infty)$ such that
$\dx\mathrm{vol}_{\rho} = \lambda(\rho,\cdot)\, \dx\mathrm{vol}_0$.
Fix $0 < \delta < \varepsilon$.
By compactness of $[0,\delta] \times \partial_{\infty}M$, there exists $c>0$ with
$$
\forall (\rho,x) \in [0,\delta]\times \partial_{\infty}M,\quad
\lambda(\rho,x) \geqslant c.
$$
Finally, notice that the volume form of $g$ satisfies on $K_{\varepsilon}$
$$
\dx\mathrm{vol}_g = \frac{1}{\rho^{n/2}} \dx\rho\wedge \dx\mathrm{vol}_{\rho}.
$$
Fix $0 < t \leqslant\delta < \varepsilon$, and let $K_{t,\delta} = \rho^{-1}([t,\delta])$.
Then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Vol}_g(K_{t,\delta})
&= \int_{K_{t,\delta}} \dx\mathrm{vol}_g \\
&= \int_{[t,\delta]\times \partial_{\infty}M} \frac{1}{\rho^{n/2}} \dx\rho\wedge \dx\mathrm{vol}_{\rho} \\
&= \int_t^{\delta}\int_{\partial_{\infty}M} \frac{1}{\rho^{n/2}}\lambda\, \dx\rho\wedge\dx\mathrm{vol}_0 \\
&\geqslant \int_t^{\delta}\frac{1}{\rho^{n/2}}\left(\int_{\partial_{\infty}M}c\,\dx\mathrm{vol}_0\right)\dx\rho \\
&= c\mathrm{Vol}_{g_0}(\partial_{\infty}M) \int_t^{\delta}\frac{1}{\rho^{n/2}}\dx\rho.
\end{align}
Now, if $n=2$, then
$$
\int_t^{\delta}\frac{1}{\rho}\dx\rho = \ln\frac{\delta}{t}.
$$
If $n>2$, then
$$
\int_t^{\delta}\frac{1}{\rho^{n/2}}\dx\rho = \frac{2}{n-2}\left(\frac{1}{t^{\frac{n-2}{2}}} - \frac{1}{\delta^{\frac{n-2}{2}}}\right).
$$
In any case, since $K_{t,\delta}\subset M$, we have
$$
\mathrm{Vol}_g(M) \geqslant \lim_{t\to 0}\mathrm{Vol}_g(K_{t,\delta}) = +\infty.
$$